# How to store homemade fresh Mozzarella Cheese

Tags: cheese-making, mozzarella

What is the key to keeping fresh Mozzarella soft.

It often turns "sticky" in refrigerator storage

Comment: Is this about storing or making the cheese? If the former, recommend you update the title; if the latter, this might be a recipe request (or it could come under "basics", like the [question on tomato paste](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11473/how-do-you-make-tomato-paste).)

Comment: fresh mozz always comes stored in water when you buy it in a punnet. have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that fresh mozzarella should be stored in the whey to keep it moist.